# Wrong CSS Path - Live Reload issue with Grunt

Tags: node.js, less, gruntjs, livereload

I have this setup in my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: false,
                    yuicompress: false,
                    optimization: 0
                },
                files: {
                    // target.css file: source.less file
                    "assets/css/main.css": "assets/css/main.less"
                },
            } 
        },
        watch: {

            styles: {
                // Which files to watch (all .less files recursively in the less directory)
                files: ['assets/css/*.less', 'assets/less/*.less'],
                tasks: ['less'],
            },
            // Live reload CSS
            css: {
                files: ['assets/css/*.css'],
                options: {
                    nospawn: true,
                    interrupt: false,
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });
    // Watch
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    // Less Complile
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less','watch']);
};
```

My sylesheet is loaded like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://project.dev/wp-content/themes/project/style.css">
```

Whenever I change the css file the I get a 404 error in the browser for this url

```
http://project.dev/assets/css/main.css?livereload=1392748371895
```

Which is of course right because the css file lives in:

```
http://project.dev/wp-content/themes/project/assets/css/main.css
```

How do I get live reload to get the right URL?

Comment: It seems to be taking the relative path from the main url. How are you  injecting livereload into the page?

Comment: Via this script:

<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the base so that `Grunt` knows where to run the application from. The files the tasks output should be set to reflect the structure `Wordpress` expects. Its all in the path configuration.

You can achieve a more flexible `path` structure if you configure it early on Grunt's configuration. *Assuming that the `Gruntfile.js` is in the root of your site (besides the `wp-content` directory)*, you could do the following configuration:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // configurable paths
    cfg: {
        dist: './wp-content/themes/project'
    },
    // tasks configurations come here...
});
```

Then on the `watch` task, you'd set:

```
livereload: {
    files: ['<%= cfg.dist %>/assets/css/*.css'],
    options: {
        nospawn: true,
        interrupt: false,
        livereload: true
    }
}
```

The resulting `Gruntfile.js` would look like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        // configurable paths
        cfg: {
            dist: './wp-content/themes/project'
        },
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: false,
                    yuicompress: false,
                    optimization: 0
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= cfg.dist %>/assets/css/main.css': '<%= cfg.dist %>/assets/css/main.less'
                }
            } 
        },
        watch: {
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= cfg.dist %>/assets/css/*.less', '<%= cfg.dist %>/assets/less/*.less'],
                tasks: ['less']
            },
            css: {
                files: ['<%= cfg.dist %>/assets/css/*.css'],
                options: {
                    nospawn: true,
                    interrupt: false,
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less','watch']);
};
```

You'd still have to adjust the above to fit your needs, but the principle is there.

Comment: Understood. The reasoning for keeping the gruntfile.js in the theme directory and running grunt from there, was that I could keep everything neatly in the git repository (including the Gruntfilejs). within in the theme directory. Doesn't make sense to create the git repository in the root WP folder as I would need to ignore a lot of files.

Comment: @ZenoPopovici using `.gitignore` does make sense for me, if that helps solving the project's base problem. As it is now, the `livereload` you have on your question treats the path `files: ['assets/css/*.css']` as the path for the `CSS` files, but that is not correct considering the path that exists before the theme folder... (as you already found out, hence the question). :)

Comment: Just saying... my answer may not be the solution you want to implement, but it does solve the problem you're trying to solve. ;)

Comment: Thanks Wallace. You're most probably right. I'll take this approach from now on, as I realized that for some projects custom plugins are necessary and therefore they too belong in git.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a setup I can test this on, but I think you need to set the base option:

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        base: 'www-root'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See doc here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/blob/master/README.md#basic-use

Read down through multiple servers if relevant.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm not using contrib-connect. I'm using contrib-watch.

Comment: Sorry - My miss there, is this resolved using the cwd option and setting the spawn directory? https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionscwd

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Let me give a little bit more background.

I'm new to node & grunt, I'm creating a wordpress theme and my package.json and Gruntfile.js are in the /wp-content/themes/themename folder.

I'm creating everything there so that I can easily manage things trough version control in the theme folder.

Do I have to move the package.json and the Gruntfile.js in the wordpress root folder? I don't want to do that but right now everything I tried doesn't work.

Thanks for the patience.

Comment: It may sound biased since I've given another answer but I think the problem here is not necessarily with the `livereload` missing a base but the project itself missing a clearer configuration for the base. Personally, I would move `Grunt` files to the `Wordpress` root folder and treat it as the base - using `.gitignore` to ignore folders other than the active theme folder. Once that is done the configuration on my answer would take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Wallace just answered it better so he got the bounty.