# Grunt autoprefixer not prefixing

Tags: css, gruntjs, vendor-prefix

I'm dabbling into Grunt. I'm trying to write a task that autoprefix automatically my css.

Here is my Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 8 versions']
      },
      files: {
        'css/styles.css': 'css/styles.css'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: ['sass/**/*.{scss,sass}','sass/_partials/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass:dist', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: ['*.html', '*.php', 'js/**/*.{js,json}', 'css/*.css','img/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    },
    sass: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'css/styles.css': 'sass/styles.scss'
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dist', 'autoprefixer', 'watch']);
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

When i run grunt, It says it's running the task fine but when i check the css files, nothing is processed.

Am i missing something? ( answer is yes but I'd like to know what :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`livereload` within the `watch` task is very picky about path. Look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862846/wrong-css-path-live-reload-issue-with-grunt/22054949#22054949).

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to offer and alternative easier solution to this question. The accepted answer is overkill for this posters problem. What is going on with the OP's question is that the autoprefixer task is missing a target, such as `dist:`, before the files it is supposed to convert. Thus:

```
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
    browsers: ['last 8 versions']
  },
  files: {
    'css/styles.css': 'css/styles.css'
  }
},
```

Should be:

```
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
    browsers: ['last 8 versions']
  },
  dist: { // Target
    files: {
      'css/styles.css': 'css/styles.css'
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to just target the src and not files?